# progress using Knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to use progressive bar in my HTML page.i am using 'progress', the value is not being replicated when i am binding ko variable with the progressive bar.

How do I add value as a text in the middle of the progressive bar?

```js
function myFunction1() {
       return document.getElementById("myProgress").value = "75";
  //Actually the value 75 is coming from the ko variable.I can print this variable.
  //Only issue in updating the value in progress
}
```

```html
<progress id="myProgress" value="javascript:myFunction1()" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: Please provide a lot more details - a cutdown example, INCLUDING the knockout parts, that demonstrate the issue. What you've given us here is basically useless.

Comment: Knockout par is very complicated, so i just added the value.Am not having any issues with the ko variable, as i can see the dynamic changes. The olny issue is with the value part in the progress tag.

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like you are doing is using the function return value for the value of your progress bar. Sadly, this function is only evaluated once. I'd advice for binding the `ko.observable` directly on your progress bar like this:

```
<progress id="myProgress" data-bind="attr: { value: myProgressObservable }" max="100">
</progress>
```

*Ps; See the knockout docs for more information about the attribute binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html*

Comment: @ShankarP You're welcome :) Also please consider accepting this answer :)